# Thunk action creators dispatch another thunk action creators, but typescript throw an error. What type should i add?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, thunk

How make typescript not complain or how to fix it?

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PostActionTypes'.
>     Type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is missing the following properties from type 'GetDetailsFailAction': type, payload [2345]
>   (alias) initPosts(): (dispatch: Dispatch) => void
>   import initPosts

What type i need to add when dispatching thunk action inside another thunk action?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { initPosts } from "./init";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { AppActions } from "../types/actions";

export const deletePost = (id: string) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<AppActions>) => {
    axios
      .delete(`https://#####/posts/${id}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch(initPosts()); // error here
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

initPosts action

```
import axios from "axios";
import { AppActions } from "../types/actions";
import { IPost } from "../types/postInterface";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";

export const initPostsStart = (): AppActions => {
  return {
    type: "INIT_POSTS_START"
  };
};

export const initPostsSuccess = (allPosts: IPost[]): AppActions => {
  return {
    type: "INIT_POSTS_SUCCESS",
    payload: allPosts
  };
};

export const initPostsFail = (error: string): AppActions => {
  return {
    type: "INIT_POSTS_FAIL",
    payload: error
  };
};

export const initPosts = () => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<AppActions>) => {
    dispatch(initPostsStart());
    axios
      .get("https://#####/posts")
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(initPostsSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(initPostsFail(error.message));
      });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#usage-with-redux-thunk),

You should type it as,

```
import { ThunkAction as ReduxThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';

type ThunkAction = ReduxThunkAction<void, IState, unknown, Action<string>>;
export const initPosts = (): ThunkAction => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(initPostsStart());
    axios
      .get("https://#####/posts")
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(initPostsSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(initPostsFail(error.message));
      });
  };
};
```